# Where did they get this value from?

Tags: interrupt, msp430, code-composer, datasheet

So I've got the following example code that prints the temperature of a connected temp sensor.
But this line I don't understand

```
 NVIC->IP[20] = 0x60; //Set interupt priority to 3
```

How does a hex value of 0x60 corresponds to a priority of 3? And where did they got this from.

FULL CODE BELOW:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

uint8_t data;
#include "msp.h"
#include "msp432.h"
#include "math.h"

void pin_setup(){
    P1->SEL0 |= 0xC0;
    P1->SEL1 &= 0xC0;
}
void twi_master_setup(){
    EUSCI_B0->CTLW0 = 0x0001;
    EUSCI_B0->CTLW0 = 0x0F51;  

    EUSCI_B0->CTLW1 = 0x0008; // Set auto stop on byte counter
    EUSCI_B0->TBCNT = 0x0001; // Set byte counter to 1

    EUSCI_B0->BRW = 0x0040; // Set clock prescaler to 64
    EUSCI_B0->CTLW0 &= ~0x0001; // Release software reset
    EUSCI_B0->IE |= 0x0003; 
    
    NVIC->IP[20] = 0x60; //Set interupt priority to 3
    NVIC->ISER[0] |= 0x00100000; // Enable interupt

}


void i2cB0receive() {

    EUSCI_B0->I2CSA = 0x48;
    EUSCI_B0->CTLW0 &= ~0x0010;//Switch to receiver mode
    EUSCI_B0->CTLW0 |= 0x0002;//Issue start condition;

}
void EUSCIB0_IRQHandler() {
    uint16_t temp;
    temp = EUSCI_B0->IFG; // copy interrupt flags to temp variable
    if(temp & 0x0001){
        EUSCI_B0->CTLW0 |= 0x0004;//EUSCI_B_CTLW0_SWRST;
        EUSCI_B0->IFG &= ~0x0001;
        data = EUSCI_B0->RXBUF;


    }
}

int main(void)
{
    WDT_A->CTL = WDT_A_CTL_PW | WDT_A_CTL_HOLD;

    pin_setup();
    twi_master_setup();

    while(1){
        i2cB0receive();
        int8_t temp = (int8_t)data;
        printf("%d\n",temp);
    }
}
```

I've found this table in the datasheet but 0x60 to binary = 01100000 corresponds to the 6th and the 7th bit.
This doesn't come close to a priority of 3.

Maybe I'm using the wrong table?